# Priority Queue ArrayList HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, priority-queue

I have a HashMap whose key is distance and value is ArrayList which contains a list of vertices which are at a particular distance (i.e. key)

I want to make Priority Queue of HashMap(priority based on keys) to get all the vertices which are at a particular distance at a time.

is it possible to make such priority Queue (unbounded one) ? 
Could anyone help please ?

Comment: This might help https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use class to encapsulate the distance and vertices. Implements the `Comparable` interface or pass the `Comparator` object when you'll `new` the `PriorityQueue`. you can do this following ...

```
class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
  int distance;
  List<Vertex> list;

  public Node(int distance, List<Vertex> list) {
    this.distance = distance;
    this.list = list;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Node o) {

      // your compare logic goes here
      return Integer.compare(this.distance, o.distance);
  }
}
```

=====

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    PriorityQueue<Node> q = new PriorityQueue<>();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

PriorityQueue is unbounded and it grows dynamically based on the number of elements in the Queue. It has internal capacity at any given time and it is increased as the elements are added.

But I don't see much sense in transforming it to PriorityQueue, if you want your map sorted by key i.e. distances then use LinkedHashMap which is sorted by distances.

```
 Map<Double, List<Vertex>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 //...
 map = map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: hi Zildyan Thank you...- my requirement is dijkstra's like. in an iteration min distance vertex is seleted and all outgoing edges of the seleted vertex is relaxed to find new distances of vertices. I want to avoid sorting for this as i feel it is computationally expensive for this requirement.